# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In LINQ I want make thw follow query:

```
_tareaRepositorio.ObtenerTodo()
  .Where(
   x =>
     Convert.ToDateTime(x.FechaCreacion.ToString("d")) >= fechaInicial &&
     Convert.ToDateTime(x.FechaCreacion.ToString("d")) <= fechaFinal).ToList();
```

But, at the moment of execute the query appears the follow mistake:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How I can fix that ?

**EDIT**

The trouble is that I need compare just date, not time ...

Comment: What type is `x.FechaCreacion`?

Comment: Don't try to convert the date to a string and then parse it back to a date again; just use the original date as a date.

Comment: I just want to jump in and add 2 links I find very important when working with semi-complex to complex entity framework LINQ queries. [CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I need built like this because I need compare: 01/01/2012 12:00:00 againts 01/05/2012 12:00:00 and without .ToString("d") I will compare: 01/01/2012 01:55:23 againts 01/01/2015 12:00:00 ... In this way I will lost data ...

Comment: Does LINQ to Entities support `date.Today` to extract only the date?

Comment: No, and also not support this: `x.FechaCreacion.Date`

**The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.**

Comment: Here [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499987/LINQ-query-to-compare-only-date-part-of-DateTime) Says some thing but you have to call two times `.ToList()` extension method ... This become in non optimal operation ...

Comment: By the moment the solution is like @Richard says ... I will sacrify the fact of lost data ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

**EDIT:** Add `DbFunctions.TruncateTime()` to get the desired effect

```
_tareaRepositorio.ObtenerTodo()
    .Where( x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.FechaCreacion) >= fechaInicial &&
                 DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.FechaCreacion) <= fechaFinal)
    .ToList();
```

The exception you are getting is because the `Convert.ToDateTime` is a .NET method that cannot be converted into SQL. Normally this should be done after the query has been materialized (i.e. using `.ToList()` before the `Where`) but in your particular case it is unnecesary since `DateTime` objects can be compared using `>=` and `<=` and Entity Framework can convert it to SQL successfully

Now if you only want to compare the Date part of the Datetime you can use the method `DbFunctions.TruncateTime()` which lives inside `System.Data.Entity` namespace. This method will allow EF to correctly truncate the date in SQL

Comment: The troube is that I need compare just date, not time ... As you suggest I will compare datetime vs date and like this I will loss data ...

Comment: @FreddyCastelblancoMacias Please include that in your question, also I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get entities between two dates, compare as dates:

```
var result = content.Table.Where(x => x.date >= startDate
                                 && x.date <= endDate)
                           .ToList();
```

where `startDate` and `endDate` are both `DateTime`.

Converting to strings means you are at the mercy of the current culture (locale) settings. With the invariant culture the default date format is American, so they do not compare lexicographically with any useful sense.

Comment: Converting to strings *just doesn't work* as is indicated by the error the OP was getting...

Answer (score 0):

Return your result with AsEnumerable() then convert it to list.

It will work i am facing the same problem as you this solution might be work.

Answer (score 0):

use DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(2019,1,28,0,0,0)