# linq with select distinct and count for the C# application

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two sql query, I have already tested both queries are working. What I need to convert to Linq  query for the dropdown list(MVC C#). Are there any way to Linq query should display only date without time?
Eg only date 2015-09-30

```
  SELECT DISTINCT DelDate  from Location where    
  DStatus = 'true' and FState = 'true'
```

output

```
2015-09-30 14:06:37.000
2015-09-30 14:14:09.547
```

My second query, I need to convert linq list only

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CouName) AS StatusCount  FROM Location  where   
DlStatus = 'true' and FState = 'true'  and CouName = 'Alan'
```

Comment: `DelDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` to print only date portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the `SQL` in your question, equivalent `Linq` will be

SELECT DISTINCT DelDate  from Location where  DStatus = 'true' and FState = 'true'

```
var delDates = Location
  .Where(l => l.DStatus == "true" && l.FState == "true")
  .Select(f => f.DelDate)
  .Distinct();
```

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CouName) AS StatusCount  FROM Location  where DlStatus = 'true' and FState = 'true'  and CouName = 'Alan'

```
var statusCount = Location
  .Where(l => l.DStatus == "true" && l.FState == "true" && l.CouName == "Alan")
  .Select(f => f.CouName)
  .Distinct()
  .Count();
```

Comment: `DSStatus` and `FState` are most likely BIT(1) in database.

Comment: @RichardSchneider possible. If op confirms that I'll change to `.Where(l => l.DStatus && l.FState)` etc.

Comment: delDates is working for me.  Are there anyway to remove time?

Comment: f.DelDate.Date would take only the date ;]

Comment: Do I need to add last line Distinct().ToList();

Comment: @Rob `Distinct()` gives you back an `IEnumerable`, so whenever you iterate over that or do a `ToList()` you'll get the actual result of the query. If you immediately want the result set as `List`, you can add a `ToList()` to the end.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
db.Location.Where(x=>x.DStatus == "true" && x.FState == "true")
           .Select(y=>y.DelDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).Distinct().ToList();
```

and this

```
    db.Location.Where(x=>x.DStatus == "true" && x.FState == "true" && x.CouName == "Alan")
               .Select(y=>y.CouName).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: Your first query missing Distinct

Comment: Your first query will come error No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Rob : what is the datatype of `DelDate`?

Comment: data type is DateTime

Comment: @Rob Nullable DateTime?

Comment: Di I need add end .Distinct().ToList();?

Comment: @Rob : Yes, you can. Updated/

Comment: It say "Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: look at this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240879/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-datetime-todatetimesyste

Answer (score 1):

for first query to get only date you can truncate time at selection `.Date` will get only Date and remove Time portion.

```
var dates = Location.Where(l => l.DStatus && l.FState)
                    .Select(f => f.DelDate.Date)
                    .Distinct();
```

for second query

```
var count = Location.Where(l => l.DStatus && l.FState && l.CouName == "Alan")
                    .Select(f => f.CouName)
                    .Distinct()
                    .Count();
```

Comment: How can truncate ? using DelDate.Date?